# How to Use Models with QML?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qml

I have a GUI written in qml and c++. 
There are 2 comboboxes (qt control 5.1). Second combobox has to update at runtime whenever the value of the first one is changed.

```
maincontext->setContextProperty("typemodel", QVariant::fromValue(m_typemodel));

maincontext->setContextProperty("unitmodel", QVariant::fromValue(m_unitmodel));
```

These are 2 models that I give to qml from c++.

```
ComboBox {
    id: typebox

    anchors.left: text1.right
    anchors.leftMargin: 5
    signal changed(string newtext)

    width: 70
    height: 23
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 37
    model: typemodel

    onCurrentTextChanged: {

        mainwin.unitGenerator(typebox.currentText);

    }
```

This is the first combobox. As you see, the c++ model of second combobox is updated every time the value of the first is changed (mainwin.unitGenerator(typebox.currentText)). But it does not seem to update the combobox's model.

How can I update qml's model on runtime?

Comment: You need to inform QML that your model has been updated by the C++. This is not done by default by Qt engine. So you might need to call `setContextProperty()` every time your model changes

Comment: @koopajah Will it be good practice to setcontext every time? Won't there be any memory leaks? I thought about that but I have a feeling it is not a good idea to solve this problem like that

Comment: I think it is a viable solution. Another one would be to "loop" your C++ model in QML and create a new `ListModel` based on it. Then when your model in C++ is updated it needs to send a signal that you catch in QML and then you update your `ListModel` accordingly. You could also use `QAbstractListModel`. More info here : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To even begin to address your issue, we'd need to see what the `unitGenerator` method does. If you're using a custom model, it's almost certain that you're not correctly implementing the notifications. My bet at the moment would be that you're not signaling the model reset.

Below is a complete code example that shows how you can tie a `QStringListModel` to an editable `ListView` and to `ComboBox`es. The second `ComboBox`'s model is regenerated based on the selection from the first one. This presumably approximates your desired functionality.

Note the specific handling of roles done by the `QStringListModel`. The model treats the display and edit roles almost the same: they both are mapped to the string value in the list. Yet when you update a particular role's data, the `dataChanged` signal carries *only* the role that you've changed. This can be used to break a binding loop that might be otherwise present in the model editor item (TextInput). When you use a custom model, you may need to implement similar functionality.

The `display` role is used to bind the combo boxes to the model. The `edit` role is used to pre-populate the editor objects. The editor's `onTextChanged` signal handler is updating the `display` role, and this doesn't cause a binding loop to itself. If the handler was updating the `edit` role, it would cause a binding loop via the `text` property.

### On Models in QML

There are various kinds of "models" in QML. Internally, QML will wrap almost "anything" in a model. Anything that is internally *not a QObject* yet can still be a model (say a `QVariant`), won't be  notifying anyone about anything.

For example, a "model" based on `QVariant` that wraps an `int` will not issue notifications, because `QVariant` is not a `QObject` that could signal changes.

Similarly, if your "model" is tied to a property value of a class derived from `QObject`, but you fail to `emit` the property change notification signal, it also won't work.

Without knowing what your model types are, it's impossible to tell.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300; height: 300
    ListView {
        id: view
        width: parent.width
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: column.top
        model: model1
        spacing: 2
        delegate: Component {
            Rectangle {
                width: view.width
                implicitHeight: edit.implicitHeight + 10
                color: "transparent"
                border.color: "red"
                border.width: 2
                radius: 5
                TextInput {
                    id: edit
                    anchors.margins: 1.5 * parent.border.width
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    text: edit // "edit" role of the model, to break the binding loop
                    onTextChanged: model.display = text
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Column {
        id: column;
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        Text { text: "Type";  }
        ComboBox {
            id: box1
            model: model1
            textRole: "display"
            onCurrentTextChanged: generator.generate(currentText)
        }
        Text { text: "Unit"; }
        ComboBox {
            id: box2
            model: model2
            textRole: "display"
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QStringListModel>
#include <QQmlContext>

class Generator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QStringListModel * m_model;
public:
    Generator(QStringListModel * model) : m_model(model) {}
    Q_INVOKABLE void generate(const QVariant & val) {
        QStringList list;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
            list << QString("%1:%2").arg(val.toString()).arg(i);
        }
        m_model->setStringList(list);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QStringListModel model1, model2;
    Generator generator(&model2);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QStringList list;
    list << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four";
    model1.setStringList(list);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("model1", &model1);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("model2", &model2);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("generator", &generator);

    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Why do you #include main.moc at the bottom of main.cpp and not the top?

Comment: @GPPK Because it contains generated code that depends on the headers included by `main.cpp`, and can possibly depend on the declarations or inline definitions in `main.cpp` as well. It must be treated as if it was code that you typed into `main.cpp`.

Comment: Inclusion of "main.moc" in the user code like this, is new to me. Is that normal thing or hack? Could you please refer me to the documentation which talks about such inclusion?

Comment: @Nawaz The documentation generally doesn't talk about at all. It's not a hack. moc generates code for you that depends on some declarations. If that generated code depends on declarations that only exist in a `.cpp` file, there's no other place for you to put it: the declarations are not visible outside of the file. This is a common technique when writing single-file utilities (where everything is in `main.cpp`), or when merging multiple .cpp files to speed up compilation.

Comment: @KubaOber: I'm just wondering if the moc file doesn't know them, and how does it get generated in the first place? Where does it get generated from?

Comment: @Nawaz It gets generated from the declarations in the same file where moc output is included. This isn't a problem when you're moc-ing a header file - then moc output is compiled separately and it *includes* the header file. But when you moc a .cpp file, the moc'd output can't include the .cpp file. It must instead be included in the .cpp file, at the very end. You need to moc every .cpp file where a `Q_OBJECT` macro appears.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually more of an answer/comment to the answer of @KubaOber.

I found that it is actually not necessary to do any special tricks using multiple roles if you bind to the correct event:

```
onAccepted: model.edit = text
```

works just fine and does not create any update loop (as it is only called on "human"/input modification).