# Reusability of Code from a Xamarin Project in a Qt C++ Project

Tags: c++, linux, qt, xamarin, mvvm

i have a simple App which was developed in Xamarin for Mobile devices and Windows Desktop. For its development C#, (Galasoft) MVVM-Light and the Repository Pattern was used. The Backend is not a part of this Project. But for a complete picture, REST EndPoints are used.

Now i question myself what of the previous Project can be used if i want write the same App (for Linux) in Qt & C++. So far i know that:

- Views have to be completly rewritten because Qt uses "qml" and not XAML
- Also Qt doesn't use 'Bindings' like it is possible in MVVM/C#/XAML. But there are some kind of alternative way for it, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648257/how-to-implement-wpf-like-mvvm-in-qt-c-qml)
- Models should be relativley be easy to be reused.

To minimize the 'rewrite' Part of Code i also found a C# to C++ Wrapper but so far only for methods not for whole Classes. See yourself [here](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/dllexport.aspx)

Does anybody have further Tipps or can correct my statements if they are wrong in some aspect?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking from experience, my best tip is to avoid trying to use existing code, and instead write a new app from scratch in `C++/Qt`. It may be alluring that you already have an application, but trying to port it will probably be a more painful process than simply rewriting it, and you will also miss opportunities to benefit from Qt's strong sides. For example the declarative nature of `QML` does not have a clear counterpart, and you definitely want to leverage that to the full.

The only exception is if you (like you say) have a very self-contained library part that you will easily be able to wrap and reuse. But even that will be a liability at build time. I found that keeping your entire codebase in `C++/Qt5` makes build and deployment very simple and elegant. The tools that come with `Qt` such as **qmake**, **qbs** and **QtCreator** are really good for cross-platform.

Other than this, here are some comments:

- The way to create **bindings** in your link is correct. That is how you do it with `QML`. But it's not the only way. There are many way to go about it. Here is documentation for the alternatives: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html
- In the `C++` side, you will be dealing with something called signals and slots which is very well documented here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html.

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Basically and honestly it is a complete rewrite. Reason for that Qt is C++ while Xamarin is mostly C#.