# Using Qt’s signals and slots when the same signal can come from multiple places

Tags: c++, qt

Qt’s signal and slot mechanism works fine when you have events that occur in one component and need to be handled by one or more other components.

My situation is that an event can occur in either of two classes and it needs to be handled by each of those classes (as well as by a couple of others). For example, suppose that I’m writing a modal text editor. The mode can be changed by the user (by pressing a button on a toolbar) or by the application (when a new file is opened). I might have

```
// Toolbar.h

signals:
    void user_changed_mode(EditingMode new_mode);
    // connected to AppController::user_changed_mode

public slots:
    void mode_changed(EditingMode new_mode);

// AppController.h

signals:
    void mode_changed(EditingMode new_mode);
    // connected to Toolbar::mode_changed

public slots:
    void user_changed_mode(EditingMode new_mode);
```

It just seems awkward to me to have two signals that convey the same information but which have different names (and likewise for the slots). Is there a simple way to use the signals and slots mechanism when the same event can originate from multiple places?

Comment: The name of the signal/slot doesn't have to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember that the signals and slots can have any name that is a valid C++ identifier, and that their scope is the class in which you declare them.

So, the signals and slots in multiple classes can have the same name as long as these names are meaningful and not misleading.

But, there's another problem. You most likely have a change loop, and your code will crash due to infinite recursion. When the toolbar's mode is changed, it must emit a `mode_changed` signal, otherwise you're breaking the typical semantics such code should have. So, assume that the controller emits a mode changed signal, then the toolbar receives it, changes *its* mode, and emits a confirmatory signal, the controller does the same, and so it goes forever.

The way to break such loops is to distinguish the signal triggered at the first invocation from the signals subsequently emitted as results of such a change. You can use a discriminating boolean, or re-purpose `Qt::ItemDataRole`, with `Qt::EditRole` for the source of the change, and `Qt::DisplayRole` for all subsequent indications of the change - that's how you'd [break the property binding loops when using QML and models](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622443/1329652).

Thus:

```
enum class EditingMode { ... };
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(EditingMode)

class Toolbar : public ... {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void modeChanged(EditingMode, Qt::ItemDataRole role = Qt::DisplayRole);
  Q_SLOT void setMode(EditingMode new_mode, Qt::ItemDataRole role = Qt::EditRole) {
    ... // perform mode changes
    if (role == Qt::EditRole) emit modeChanged(new_mode);
  }
  ...
};

class AppController : public ... {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void modeChanged(EditingMode, Qt::ItemDataRole role = Qt::DisplayRole);
  Q_SLOT void setMode(EditingMode new_mode, Qt::ItemDataRole role = Qt::EditRole) {
    ... // perform mode changes
    if (role == Qt::EditRole) emit modeChanged(new_mode);
  }
  ...
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  ...
  Toolbar toolbar1, toolbar2;
  AppController controller;
  for (auto toolbar : QList<Toolbar*>() << &toolbar1 << &toolbar2) {
    QObject::connect(toolbar, &Toolbar::modeChanged, &controller, &Controller::setMode);
    QObject::connect(&controller, &Controller::modeChanged, toolbar, &Toolbar::setMode);
  }
  ...
  toolbar1.setMode(Mode1);
  // toolbar2 gets notified, but doesn't notify anyone else again
  // controller gets notified, but doesn't notify anyone else again
  ...
  controller.setMode(Mode2);
  // toolbar1 gets notified, but doesn't notify the controller again
  // toolbar2 gets notified, but doesn't notify the controller again
}
```

Unfortunately, Qt's own Widget-module controls don't follow such a pattern, and hilarity ensues when you try to link multiple controls to follow each other... Some offer special signals that only get emitted when the user modifies the data, but not all do that, and extra signals are harder to deal with...

When you use Qt Quick, everything is fine as long as you follow this or a similar pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect multiple signals to the same slot. Somewhere in your application initialization you just connect the signals from each object to the same slot:

```
connect(object1, SIGNAL(object1_changed_mode(EditingMode)),
        receiverInAppController, SLOT (mode_changed(EditingMode)) );

connect(object2r, SIGNAL(object2_changed_mode(EditingMode)),
        receiverInAppController, SLOT(mode_changed(EditingMode)) );
```

Also note that Qt5 has an alternative [simplified syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). Qt5 remains compatible with the above notation, though.

Finally, the signals can also have the same name. The only requirement is that each signal is declared individually in the class definition of each object.